# Создать консольное пакетное приложение Java c использованием шаблона MVC

Tags: java, mvc

Решил написать универсальное приложение, для дальнейшего использования  в сети... Но пока, для простоты, хотелось бы получить следующее: Приложение - записная (адресная, телефонная) книга. Мы получаем некую строку с параметрами и аргументами,  - ее, видимо, нужно распарсить и затем, Контроллер должен поработать и выдать результат на View (например, в метод show()). Затем все сохраняется в файл(в БД нет необходимости, пока)...

Comment: На помощь в чём вы надеетесь?

Comment: У меня пока нет конкретной стратегии, как это реализовать..Только общие соображения. Хотелось бы какой-то пример, или правильное направление действий. Ранее, - пакетных консольных приложений не писал, только интерактивные.

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console не совсем ваш язык, но разобраться будет не сложно. Могу ещё посоветовать https://elisdn.ru/blog/124/psr7-console-db-assets

Comment: @ArchDemon Спасибо! Попробую вникнуть и разобраться...